# Python: Closing and removing files

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to unzip a file, and read one of the extracted files, and delete the extracted files.

1. Files extracted (e.g. we got file1 and file2)
2. Read file1, and close it.

   ```
   with open(file1, 'r') as f:
       data = f.readline()
   f.close()
   ```
3. Do something with the "data".
4. Remove the files extracted.

   ```
   os.remove(file1)
   ```

Everything went fine, except it received these messages at the end. The files were also removed. How do I close the files properly?

```
    /tmp/file1: No such file or directory
    140347508795048:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('/tmp/file1','r')
    140347508795048:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:
```

**UPDATE:**
(My script looks similar to these)

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import subprocess, os

infile = "filename.enc"
outfile = "filename.dec"
opensslCmd = "openssl enc -a -d -aes-256-cbc -in %s -out %s" % (infile, outfile)   
subprocess.Popen(opensslCmd, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE,      close_fds=True)
os.remove(infile)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The errors you see are not errors as Python would report them. They mean something other than Python tried to *open* these files, although it's hard to tell what from your little snippet.

If you're simply trying to retrieve some data from a zip file, there isn't really a reason to extract them to disk. You can simply read the data directly from the zip file, extracting to memory only, with `zipfile.ZipFile.open`.

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. It's good to know. The process involves taking one of the extracted files as input into "openssl" command and execute through subprocess. `subprocess.Popen(mycommand, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)`. That is what's causing the error. I'm still looking for a workaround.

Answer (score 3):

No need to close a file handle when using `with` with a `file` context manager, the handle is automatically closed when the scope have changed, i.e. when readline is done.

See [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: Then why is it showing the file errors the script? I removed the f.close(), it didn't help.

Comment: I think you need to add some more code above to show what is the cause of this, hard to tell from your snippet

Comment: I found what is causing this: `subprocess.Popen(mycommand, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, close_fds=True)`. The command is just an openssl command that input one of the files that I extracted. How do I do it properly? I'm sorry for these newbie questions.

Comment: @superNobody post a new question, don't forget to post all of your code. This Q is accepted; hence people might skip reading it...